# How Do I make an image go behind an other layer

Tags: css, html, wordpress, web

Example[1]http://themeforest.net/item/skilt-a-wordpress-theme-for-frequent-bloggers/7936499?ref=tbd

How do i get the affect of the image how there is a background image then a background color for the text (extra, and can i get the text background to flow along the top)? i know i am asking a vague question but i am still a nub. ^_^ 
Thank you (in advance if you can answer it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website has a div with a background image that has a fixed position and covers the entire browser window.

```
body {
    background-color: #0c0c0c;
}

#background-image { 

    opacity: 0.7;
    background-image: url(some_image.jpg);

    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    background-position: center;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

With HTML like this:

```
<div id="background-image"></div>
<div class="container>
    <div id="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum some stuff</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Its a very cool effect and you should try replicate it on a website that you make. Keep working on it until you figure it out.

Here is a good place to start: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: Thanks... explained alot to more :)

Answer (score 0):

You can always set both a background image and a background color at the same time with CSS:

```
body {
  background-image:url(url/to/your/image);
  background-color:#CCCCCC;
}
```

EDIT: if you are asking about how the background image stays in place, you can also add `background-attachment:fixed;`. This is a lot simpler than making a separate div with a fixed position, and it is semantically correct too.